# How can I capture data from Umbraco Forms?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I have a requirement to provide a GUI forms editor so that non-technical users can create forms. One of the tools I am looking at is the Umbraco Forms tool (formerly Umbraco Contour).

I want to be able to capture submitted data in an Action Method, process it in some way, and then send it to a web service.

Looking into the Umbraco docs, it looks as if forms generated by the Umbraco Forms tool are rendered by a macro and automatically submit data to the Umbraco database - there doesn't seem to be any way to intercept the submitted data.

Is that correct, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a custom `WorkflowType`.  Workflows allow you to perform further actions by attaching them to certain events, i.e. when a form is submitted or approved etc.  There are some options available by default for sending emails and posting data to a URL of your choice but you can add your own if these don't meet your requirements.

I suggest that you take a look at the Umbraco Forms documentation:
https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Products/UmbracoForms

which includes a guide for adding `WorkflowTypes`:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/products/umbracoforms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype

Comment: Thanks for the tip Robert - that does look like the way to go.